# Batch File: Search for a particular file in all drives and replace substring

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed

I have tried a python version and a find / sed version, but we since we have a very wide mix of pc's with different windows versions, I have not been successful and i just dont know what to do. Due to the mix bag of software versions, I am going to assume that a batch file script is going to work on all of them.

I need to run a batch file on pc's to look in all drives for a particular file and replace a substring in that file that is a url and replace it with the url and port number in it.

HELP PLEASE!

Comment: it could take hours to find  a single file on all drives.Is there a specific dis structure that could point where the file can be found?

Comment: @npocmaka The is not too much content on these pc's, so the search should be relatively quick

Comment: wich version of windows are in the panel (XP, 7, 8, Server since 2000, ...) to know wich available tools we could use. We ca assume there is only fixed local drive (we can limit to c: -> e: for exemple) ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Thank you. There is XP, 7, windows xp embedded, windows 7 embedded. Yes, only fixed drives C: to f:

Comment: @NeronLeVelu There is also a windows 8 pc

Comment: natively, i only see Powershell or VBscript (to check with W8 for VBS) that can do it. Command/batch is a bit tricky for search and replace. Another otpion is to add some tools like cygwin (a copy of sed and find should be enough) and use a batch. otherwise, a "compiled" 32 bit version application (C, ... ) but a bit heavy for this. Thus, a powershell script should be your choice

Comment: Or can you make a thumb drive that has an environment with the required tools, and then take that from one machine to another? Good luck.